# Type-level Polymorphism in haskell

Tags: haskell, types, polymorphism

I'm working through the paper [De bruijn notation as a nested datatype](https://www.cs.ox.ac.uk/richard.bird/online/BirdPaterson99DeBruijn.pdf) by Richard Bird and Ross Paterson. At one one point a fold operation over a term gets defined:

```
infixl 9 :@

data Expr a =
      Var a
    | (Expr a) :@ (Expr a)
    | Lam (Expr (Maybe a)

foldT ::
    (forall a. a -> n a) ->
    (forall a. n a -> n a -> n a) ->
    (forall a. n (Maybe a) -> n a) ->
    Expr b -> n b
foldT v _ _ (Var x) = v x
foldT v a l (fun :@ arg) = a (foldT v a l fun) (foldT v a l arg)
foldT v a l (Lam body) = l (foldT v a l body)
```

... and further a generalized version that allows manipulations of the values of free vars:

```
gfoldT ::
    (forall a. m a -> n a) ->
    (forall a. n a -> n a -> n a) ->
    (forall a. n (Maybe a) -> n a) ->
    (forall a. (Maybe (m a)) ->  m (Maybe a)) ->    
    Expr (m b) -> n b                               
gfoldT v _ _ _ (Var x) = v x
gfoldT v a l t (fun :@ arg) = a (gfoldT v a l t fun) (gfoldT v a l t arg)
gfoldT v a l t (Lam body) = l (gfoldT v a l t (mapT t body))
```

Then the authors state that:

> In theory, we can take `m = id`, the identity type constructor, and
>   so obtain `foldT v a l = gfoldT v a l id` . (...) However, type
>   constructor polymorphism in haskell is limited, in that type
>   constructor variables may only be instantiated to datatype
>   constructors.

and further they state, that for this reason we need one-off specialized functions like `foldT` above.

I was wondering what exactly `type constructor polymorphism` means in that context (something like full `System F`?) and if something like `foldT v a l = gfoldT v a l id` can be achieved by means of the newly added type level programming features like 
`DataKinds`, `PolyKinds` or `TypeFamilies`.

Comment: When quoting a source use *actual* quote blocks, not italics. The semantic structure can be exploited by, e.g., screen readers for blind people to better present the question.

Comment: @Bakuriu, won't a screen reader recognize double quotes? I agree that quote blocks are definitely preferable for something this long, but I'm curious.

Comment: @Bakuriu, thanks for the hint!

Comment: @dfeuer What about "scary quotes"? Anyway I prefer quote blocks especially for long quotations, since they also give a clear visual indicator of what part of the text is quoted.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think that remark refers to the lack of type-level lambda abstraction. Concretely, the following is illegal, in Haskell.

```
data T m a = T (m a)

foo :: T (\t -> t) Int
foo = T 5
```

One might try to circumvent the issue using type synonyms or type families, but with no success. The following is not allowed:

```
type F t = t
foo :: T F Int
foo = T 5
```

Neither is this:

```
type family F a
type instance F a = a
foo :: T F Int
foo = T 5
```

In Haskell, the type equation `m Int ~ Int` has no solution: `m` must be a data type constructor. Indeed, among other things, the compiler relies on `m` being injective during unification, which could be easily violated with arbitrary type-level functions.

One *can* however use `m ~ Identity` and obtain `Identity Int` which is different from `Int`, but isomorphic.

At the moment, I believe [safe coercions](https://ghc.haskell.org/trac/ghc/wiki/Roles) are not powerful enough to coerce a type using `Identity Int` into the similar type which directly uses `Int`. Hence the `Identity` wrapper must be manually removed to obtain the type of the simpler fold.

Comment: (Or a type constructor or class applied to one or more arguments. I tend to call all these "first-class types", but I don't know the official terminology.) Safe coercions are sometimes sufficient, but often not.